# Flyway: Relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql, flyway

```
ERROR: relation "signature_level" does not exist
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what's the problem. Flyway is throwing me this error when migrating.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  id_code numeric NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL,
  address text,
  alt_contact_relation text NULL,
  alt_contact_phone numeric NULL,
  signature_level_id integer NULL,
  username text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  status active_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
  work_detail_id integer NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_signature_level FOREIGN KEY (signature_level_id) REFERENCES signature_level (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT FK_user_work_detail FOREIGN KEY (work_detail_id) REFERENCES work_detail (id)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

This is the signature level table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "signature_level" (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL,
  create_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
  update_time TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: In which order do you create those tables? `signature_level` has to be created before the `"user"` table. Also: you should avoid identifiers that require quoting by all means - especially `user` is a **really** bad choice for a table name as that is also the name of a built-in function. `select * from user` will return something different than `select * from "user"`

Comment: Ty brother, yeah I was wondering why it gave me an error when I tried to create the table without quotes, changed to user_acc. If you want to add an answer I'll accept it